# NativeScript + javaScript - Navigation on Dynamic pages

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I have 15 buttons on my app for navigtaion.
Lets say button 1,2,3 ... [where 1,2,3.. are button texts].
I want to redirect to Hello1, Hello2, Hello3 respectively..

```
function jump(args) {
  const button = args.object;
  const page = button.page;
  var txt = button.text;
  var pname = "Hello" + txt;
  page.frame.navigate(pname);
}
```

This unexpectedly shuts down the preview mode.

Comment: The code looks absolutely fine, just that it should include fully qualified path to the page, not just the page name unless these pages are at root of your project.

Comment: Also, preview app isn't the best place to debug an app.